# Unable to connect to web server 'AdminArea.Web'. The web server is no longer running

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, webserver, serenity

*"Unable to connect to web server 'AdminArea.Web'. The web server is no longer running"*

this error is shown up when I'm trying to execute Serenity Project

I try to run my project.

and here is the connection to my database

"fiveStarConn": {
"ConnectionString": "Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=fiveStar;Integrated Security=true;Encrypt=false;TrustServerCertificate=true",
"ProviderName": "System.Data.SqlClient"
}

Comment: Hi,@mustafa J,we couldn't reproduce the issue with only a connection string,would you provide a minimal example that could reproduce the issue?